# Regex - how to capture many words

Tags: python, regex

I have a simple regex question:

Given a string like `"test-class"` what regex should I use to get `['test','class']` (in python context)

Comment: I agree that doesn't need a regex if there are only `-` separating the words. But a regex can be useful if there are also commas, dots, or spaces between the words.

Comment: What is the goal here? To split on the `-`? To find all chunks of text that are words without dashes? What happens when there are digits, other punctuation, newlines? You need to give us sample input, expected output, including *exceptions* if there are any.

Comment: The goal is that this was to be used in Django context, not plain Python. More specificly, in URLconfs

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a regex; just use [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> 'test-class'.split('-')
['test', 'class']
```

A regex solution is still to split:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'-', 'test-class')
['test', 'class']
```

Comment: I specificly needed a regex ;)

Comment: @user3264316: why do you specifically need a regular expression?

Comment: @user3264316: You *woefully* underspecified the problem here, btw. I can only assume you wanted to split the input on dashes, and it doesn't matter what the rest of the text contains.

Answer (score 1):

```
"(\w+)"g
```

example here : http://regex101.com/r/mV9cE2

`\w` will match an return group of all alphanumeric characters

`g` modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)

Answer (score 0):

`([a-zA-Z]*)` will be enough to capture every word of a string.

Comment: Every word, and a couple of empty strings to boot. Use `+` instead of `*`

Answer (score 0):

If you are intent on using regex:

In short you define a regex which matches the things you want. Then you use `regex.matchall` to the string, and you get back the matching parts.

```
import re
$ s = 'hello-world this 32'
$ results = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]*', s)
$ print(results)
['hello', '', 'world', '', 'this', '', '', '', '']
# Now we can filter out the empty results.
$ non_empty_results = [result for result in results if result]
$ print(non_empty_results)
['hello', 'world', 'this']
```